# External library in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I want to use [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) for my assertions. Is there a way to include an external library in Postman?

Comment: You're better asking them directly - they're pretty good at responding to questions... https://www.getpostman.com/support

Comment: There's a related issue that still open: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180

Comment: Were you able to achieve your goal, if so can you please share yoru code snippet there ? I could not implement this accepted workaround unfortunately...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, `linq.js`, or any library not available in the [Postman Sandbox](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/jetpacks_sandbox) cannot be used in Postman (by default, there is a workaround).

## EDIT

Actually, if you fetch a script in a request and `eval` it, you can use it in Postman. An example is given in this blog post - http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/09/29/writing-a-behaviour-driven-api-testing-environment-within-postman/

Comment: Is there any way to create a common function in postman? I have a block of code I use a lot in many of my test scripts

Comment: I think this is worth a separate question. But if you apply what elssar says, you can just create a global variable with a set of function definitions and eval them at the beginning of your tests.

Comment: Since postman versions >=5.4.1, you can define scripts not only at test level, but also at folder level and collection level ; those scripts are executed before each execution of a sub-folder or a sub-test defined in the collection. This is a good way of re-using several times the same code

Answer (score 9):

I am doing pretty much the same than @grinderX19.

I run this once to load my global variable:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("myUtils", function myUtils() {
let utils = {};

utils.function1= function function1(Arg1, Arg2){
    <code>
};

utils.function2= function function2(Arg1, Arg2){
    <code>
};

return utils;
} + '; myUtils();'
);
```

Then, I am calling it like this in Postman requests:

```
//import the global variable
let utils = eval(globals.myUtils);

//Call a function contained by this global variable
var var1 = utils.function1(arg1, arg2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how did you store a function in a javascript object?. the above code has no syntax error but the util is an empty object

Comment: The first block is the code to put into a "global variable" (= the javascript object that stores the functions).
The second block is the code to put in your postman request (pre-request and/or test scripts).

When you eval() the global variable, that will load its code in your local request's script variable. Then you can reachthe various functions from this local variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open feature for that in Postman's bugtracker since 2015: [Loading External JS Files #1180](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180) but it doesn't seem they're actively working on it.

Meanwhile I'm using a workaround mentioned in [one of the comments](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180#issuecomment-194226755) by putting a minimized custom JS in a global variable and loading it in the beginning of each script where I'm using this code:

```
eval(postman.getGlobalVariable("environment variable key"));
```

Comment: Since postman versions >=5.4.1, you can define scripts not only at test level, but also at folder level and collection level ; those scripts are executed before each execution of a sub-folder or a sub-test defined in the collection. This is a good way of re-using several times the same code

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#custom-libraries

```
pm.sendRequest("https://example.com/your-script.js", (error, response) => {
    if (error || response.code !== 200) {
        pm.expect.fail('Could not load external library');
    }

    eval(response.text());

    // YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Example using `jalali-moment`:

```
pm.sendRequest("https://unpkg.com/jalali-moment/dist/jalali-moment.browser.js", (error, response) => {
    if (error || response.code !== 200) {
        pm.expect.fail('Could not load external library');
    eval(response.text());
    var currentTime=moment().locale('fa').format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
    console.log(currentTime);
});
```