# How to import a external javascript module into postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

How to import a external java-script module into postman?
Please show me in example.

Comment: Hey James - This is not how SO works, try reading this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [External library in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157749/external-library-in-postman)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for tips on how to write better questions. Even if others may come off as being mean, they are not trying to be. Users often get frustrated with newbies. Sorry about that. Hopefully that does not discourage you from continuing to ask questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found that Postman Sandbox environment does not allow you to import all the java-script library. It allows certain libraries only. Here is the link for that.

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/matt-ball/postman-external-require

I don't know if the solution was already available at the time the original answer was given but this is a nice workaround to include third-party libraries within postman scripts. Requires only minimal extra effort and most importantly it works! I'm using the **node-rsa** module in my scripts that way.

Comment: @Tom In the mean time I also switched from importing third party libraries into Postman to providing an external service. This is a more flexible approach. I use nodeJS with express to host a small REST application where I can operate on the data coming from Postman. You just need to make use of 'pm.sendRequest({...})' to pass your data on.