# Tests retrieved from collection variable - test failures stop subsequent tests from running

Tags: testing, postman

I have tests that I want to use in multiple API calls.

Using JavaScript from external files has been an [open issue for 6 years now](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180) but isn't officially supported (yet).  I'm [storing tests in collection variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54710287) so they can be retrieved in each APIs Tests.

The issue is tests that fail stop execution like a general JS failure.

**Tests being stored in collection variables via an API’s Pre-req**

In a setup API call I store the shared library of tests via a Pre-request Script. This is working fine.

[image]

**A "normal" test failure**

When a test is coded in an API's Test area, failures don't stop subsequent tests from running.

[image]

**A failure for a test pulled in from a collection variable**

I can pull tests from the collection variable and run them just fine. However when a Chai expectation fails it seems to be treated like a JavaScript failure instead of an test/expectation failure.

The test run fails, subsequent tests for this API don't run nor do other APIs in the collection run.

[image]

How can I have tests retrieved from a collection variable run/fail like hard coded tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in how I was calling the library function. It works as desired if the library function (with the expectations) is invoked **in** the anonymous function passed to pm.test(), not be the passed function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem I guess is how you call function from `utils`

Just `utils.payloadIs204`, not `utils.payloadIs204()`

And it works for me

[image]

---

**Update** reuse with passing parametes.

Tab pre-request

```
pm.environment.set("abc", function print(text1, text2){
    console.log(text1)
    console.log(text2)
} + "");
```

Tab Test

```
let script = pm.environment.get("abc");
eval((script + "print('name', 'age')"))
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to pass variables? Dropping the empty parentheses gives the desired behavior for test failures. Now I need to pass some arguments to the function stored as a collection variable like `utils.payloadIs204("foo", "bar", "baz")`. As soon as I add the parens and args I'm back to the issue originally reported.

Comment: @Jim Hi, I updated the answer, if it's good, don't hesitate to upvote. Thanks